# Kernel panic after upgrade to 19.04 with kernel 5.0

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, 19.04

After upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04 (Kubutu) I get a kernel panic when booting with the recent 5.0.0 kernel. Booting the previous 4.18.0 kernel works without problems.

However I cannot figure out the reason für the kernel panic. I don't find any logs, so i took two photos from the kernel panic.
[Screenshot from kernel panic (short)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQhK6.jpg)
[Screenshot from kernel panic (long)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZDSy.jpg)

The former contains the screen I "normally" get, the latter contains a screen I only got once. Can somebody advise in which direction I can further investigate?

Thank you

Comment: Mmmm... there are many causes for kernel panic, but If I am not mistaken they normally relate to faulty hardware. Most of the information is in the display you get printed. Is there any hardware that has given you trouble in the past? Perhaps try to do a fresh installation, A kernel panic occurs when the kernel has no other avenue of escape, so there must be something wrong at start-up.

Comment: Boot into previous kernel and remove the problematic kernel using ukuu (if you prefer easy way) and install it again. There must be something wrong during install of 19.04

Comment: You've got an old old BIOS from 2007, version 1.3. Go to the manufacturor's web site with model # in hand, go to the support/download area, and see if there's a newer BIOS. Report back.

Comment: @Taskalino: I don't think that hardware is the real problem because it works without problems with kernel 4.18.0

Comment: @heynnema I must create a Win98/WinME boot floppy disk in order to install a newer bios version ;-) I will try this next week because this is my work computer and I am on vacation for a few days.

Comment: @jenzuslongus what new BIOS version # did you find?

Comment: @heynnema I found version 1C. But I am not able to find a suitable boot "disk". So I decided to buy a new computer instead of going through the BIOS update procedure. Maybe that would work, but maybe the BIOS update doesn't work at all or it doesn't solve the problem.
So I decided to get a new computer. I think that's okay because it is really somewhat outdated.
Anyway, thank you all for your help!

Comment: The kernel panic issue at boot time happened several times to me in the past and again after the Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade. Nobody seems to care but you can upvote the issue and comment to show that it happens to several people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1818392